# Работа python скриптов на разных os

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ubuntu

недавно поставил на основной комп ubuntu, и столкнулся с такой проблемой

> прога на линуксе и на шинде выдают разную работу

Сорри придётся писать весь код сэмулировать ошибку не получилось
2 файла

> главный - Main.py

```
#       Импорты
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from colorama import Fore , Back , init , Style
import requests
from defs import * 
import time
import os
import sys
init()

#       Стандартные переменные
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
ROOT_DIR1 = ROOT_DIR + '/'
spisok = 1
url='https://prnt.sc/'
i = int(input('Сколько раз делать парсинг(для бесконечного парсинга используйте 0): '))#        Переменная количества 
path = ROOT_DIR1 + 'result' + '/'
headers = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; U; ABrowse 0.6; Syllable) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko)'#        ХЕДЕРЫ
#       Логика проверки папок
try:
    os.mkdir(path)
    print(Fore.RED + 'Директория созданна')
except OSError:
    print(Fore.RED + 'Директория существует')
print(Fore.CYAN+Style.BRIGHT+'Begin')
#       Прога
if i == 0:
    while True:#        Режим бесконечного парсинга
        id_pic = rand(6)
        a=url+id_pic
        reque = requests.get(a,headers={'user-agent':headers})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(reque.text, 'lxml')
        azws=soup.find('img').get('src')
        while True:#        Проверка удалённости файла
            if azws[:4] == 'http':
                down(azws,path, id_pic)
                print(Back.GREEN+Style.BRIGHT+'Файл '+id_pic+' успешно скачан')
                spisok+=1
                break
            else:
                print(Back.RED+Style.BRIGHT+'Файла '+id_pic+' не существует генерируем другой')
                id_pic = rand(6)
                a=url+id_pic
                reque = requests.get(a,headers={'user-agent':headers})
                soup = BeautifulSoup(reque.text, 'lxml')
                azws=soup.find('img').get('src')
                continue
else:#      Режим конечного парсинга   
    for i in range(0,i):
        id_pic = rand(6)
        a=url+id_pic
        reque = requests.get(a,headers={'user-agent':headers})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(reque.text, 'lxml')
        azws=soup.find('img').get('src')
        while True:#        Проверка удалённости файла
            if azws[:4] == 'http':
                down(azws,path, id_pic)
                print(Back.GREEN+Style.BRIGHT+str(spisok)+' Файл '+id_pic+' успешно скачан')
                spisok+=1
                break
            else:
                print(Back.RED+Style.BRIGHT+str(spisok)+' Файла '+id_pic +' не существует генерируем другой')
                id_pic = rand(6)
                a=url+id_pic
                reque = requests.get(a,headers={'user-agent':headers})
                soup = BeautifulSoup(reque.text, 'lxml')
                azws=soup.find('img').get('src')
                continue
#       Типо END
    print(Back.CYAN+Style.BRIGHT+'ALL')
    time.sleep(15)
```

> и просто склад функций defs.py

```
import random
import requests

def rand(n):#Рандом
    p=''
    sand = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    for i in range(0,n):
        az = random.choice(sand)
        p+=az
    return p
def down (url, path, name):#Путь с такими слешами /(Функция скачивания) url-путь до картинки path-путь для скачивания name-Имя файла
    filename = name+'.png'
    path1 = path + filename
    url_get = requests.get(url)
    with open(path1, 'wb')as f:
        f.write(url_get.content)
    pass
```

так вот в чём ошибка на шинде всё нормально, на линуксе выдаётся

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 57, in <module>
    down(azws,path, id_pic)
  File "/home/dospayne2/PYTHON/newpyser/defs.py", line 15, in down
    with open(path1, 'wb')as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/result/8vzvut.png'
```

НО КАК ЗАПИСЬ W ПРИ НЕНАХОЖДЕНИИ ФАЙЛА ДОЛЖНА ЕГО СОЗДАВАТЬ

Но только стоит под линуксом открыть прогу через vs code как всё нормально

> AHTUNG: ПОД ВИНДОЙ ЧТО ПОД vs code что под консолью всё хорошо

Comment: Должен, но точно создает? Скрипт пишет, что директория создана?

Comment: Да директория была создана когда я тестил на вс код

Comment: Ничего не изменилось, после того как я её удалил

Comment: Стоп а разве / это не корень, тоесть получается он пытается писать в корень, попробую под рутом

Comment: Вот именно, скорее всего прав не хватает.

Comment: Да он пишет в корень, но тогда возникает ещё один вопрос почему вс код пишет правильно, в папке с проэктом создаёт папку резулт

Comment: Возможно вы vscode от рута запускаете

Comment: кажись я нашёл проблему при запуске ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__) вс код выдаёт путь до папки с проэктом, а терминал выдаёт пустое место

Comment: Всё я просто добавил абсолютный путь и всё стало норм ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак ответ был очень простым надо было добавить абсолютный путь `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` вот так